# SQLAlchemy - relationship limited on more than just the foreign key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, relationship, database

I have a wiki db layout with `Page` and `Revisions`. Each Revision has a `page_id` referencing the Page, a `page` relationship to the referenced page; each Page has a `all_revisions` relationship to all its revisions. So far so common.

But I want to implement different epochs for the pages: If a page was deleted and is recreated, the new revisions have a new `epoch`. To help find the correct revisions, each page has a `current_epoch` field. Now I want to provide a `revisions` relation on the page that only contains its revisions, but only those where the epochs match.

This is what I've tried:

```
revisions = relationship('Revision',
    primaryjoin = and_(
        'Page.id == Revision.page_id',
        'Page.current_epoch == Revision.epoch',
    ),
    foreign_keys=['Page.id', 'Page.current_epoch']
)
```

[**Full code**](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/219633/) (you may run that as it is)

However this always raises **ArgumentError: Could not determine relationship direction for primaryjoin condition ...`**, I've tried all I had come to mind, it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a bad approach for doing this, how could it be done other than with a relationship?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try installing relationship after both classes are created:

```
Page.revisions = relationship(
    'Revision',
    primaryjoin = (Page.id==Revision.page_id) & \
                    (Page.current_epoch==Revision.epoch),
    foreign_keys=[Page.id, Page.current_epoch],
    uselist=True,
)
```

BTW, your test is not correct: `revisions` property loads data from database while you haven't added them to session.

**Update**: The problem in your code is that `primaryjoin` parameter is not string, so [it's not evaluated](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/ext/declarative.html#configuring-relationships). Using string in `primaryjoin` works fine:

```
class Page(Base):
    # [skipped]
    revisions = relationship(
        'Revision',
        primaryjoin = '(Page.id==Revision.page_id) & '\
                        '(Page.current_epoch==Revision.epoch)',
        foreign_keys=[id, current_epoch],
        uselist=True,
    )
```

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I don't get everything to work in the real application, but it works in the little demo, so at least this specific problem is solved now. @BTW: Ah, forgot that because we have a special init method that does the add automatically. [Updated, working code](http://paste.pocoo.org/show/220827/).

Comment: Any idea why adding it afterwards fixes that? I thought the string notation is intended to avoid such stuff? (And, when does it evaluate those strings if not after both classes are created?)

Comment: I've added an explanation and an example with proper expression in string.